# Picasso - fetch image with additional information

Tags: android, caching, picasso

I need pre-load images and save then to cache with additional information. Is there some easy solution?

My code for saving picture looks:

```
Picasso.with(mC.get()).load(image.getSrc()).fetch();
```

And I am searching for something like

```
Picasso.with(mC.get()).load(image.getSrc()).fetch().withAddInfo(image.getInfo());
```

With later use:

```
String info = Picasso.with(mC.get()).load(image.getSrc()).getAddInfo();
```

Is there a way?

Comment: Can you explain which all information of image you need ?

Comment: Just simple string/int - it would be timestamp of last update - I get this information from server and I need to compare if the image need update (invalidate->fetch)